# Gmail on iPhone: draft shows up on webmail as sent & deleted?

Tags: iphone, mail.app, gmail

My GMail account is configured on my iPhone 4S as a GMail account (which I access using the "Mail" app), not using the Exchange template.  This evening I was using that setup for composing an e-mail and decided it would be better composed on my computer, so I hit "cancel" and, when given the option, "Save as Draft."

When I went to my webmail client on my desktop, however, there was no draft.  Instead, there was an alert in the conversation I was replying to saying that there was a deleted message in that thread.  Curious, I told it to bring it back, and discovered an earlier version of my draft...

...only it treated it as a message that had been sent, complete with timestamp and mailed-by header!

I googled but didn't find anything useful; others (for instance [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/gmail/composing-and-sending-messages/Z77WJeL4FdY)) have reported a similar experience but I couldn't find an explanation anywhere.

Has anyone else run into this problem before?  Please tell me it didn't send my half-composed note when I told it to save the draft!

Comment: Do you use Mail or another app (Sparrow, the Gmail app, ...). If you used Mail, have you used the Gmail or Exchange template?

Comment: Thanks for these clarifying questions - should have thought of including that info myself, but didn't.  Question edited.